# Emails from joomla 2.5 being marked as "Phishing" mails for vendor and client

Tags: security, joomla

The Mails from Joomla to customer as well as vendor are being marked as "phishing" mails. As per solutions provided in the other posts, I checked the header and it is being marked as "Spf-Fail". What is the solution to this issue?

Many Thanks.

Comment: you are not providing much information. Can you post the complete headers of one of those mails? are they also reported as phishing if sent to a hotmail/yahoo account?.

Comment: Does the content of your email claim to be that of a bank requesting them to log onto a fake website? That could be why!!

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> Sender Policy Framework (SPF) is  is an email validation system
>   designed to prevent email spam by detecting email spoofing, a common
>   vulnerability, by verifying sender IP addresses.

You can probably fix this by changing the sender and perhaps the reply-to email addresses to match the originating domain name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Create the sending e-mail account on your server/host
2. Set up DomainKeys and SPF on your hosting account
3. Configure the account as SMTP, with the CORRECT e-mail adress on
   Joomla Global Configuration (if you need to get replies to another
   account, use the "reply to" field, but that isn't very good, as
   sometimes it counts points towards spam detectors).
4. Compose a legitimate message (i.e. NOT spam)
5. Have valid e-mails on your list (not bought lists, or collected by
   any way that doesn't have the explicit permission from the owner to
   receive e-mail).

Good luck.